# Cooked ham left out overnight

Tags: food-safety

I forgot to put the rest of the ham we ate for dinner in the fridge last night and didn't realize it until this morning. Heat wasn't on but it was probably around 57-60 degrees overnight. If I pressure cook the leftover ham with some beans, how big a chance would I be taking in eating it? I know pressure cooking should kill the bacteria, but I don't know how many toxins would have already been produced.

Just the let you know where I'm coming from, we typically eat things in our house that others would prob throw out for safety's sake (foods past their dates or left out a little longer than they should have been).

Apparently my question is too close to other questions. I would say the difference lies in two parts. One, I am planning to pressure cook the food in question which should kill the bacteria in the food. So my main question is about the toxins produced by the bacteria. And two, I am asking for an opinion, not a reiteration of food safety guidelines. As stated, our family often breaks food safety guidelines when we do not see a significant chance of it actually causing us problems.

Comment: Hi Lisa! Welcome to Seasoned Advice! Opinion-based questions are off topic for this site, so you're unlikely to get the answer you're looking for. In particular, "Is it safe to eat?" questions are strictly limited to objective, fact-based answers, which limit answers primarily to food safety guidelines.